# Mean square continuity and differentiable sample paths

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-processes

There are a number of questions involved in this post so even if you do not feel able to answer all please answer any that you can. Consider a stochastic process $Z(x)$ where $x$ is the index parameter. This process is said to be [mean-square continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stochastic_process#Mean-square_continuity) if $\mathbb{E}\left[Z(x)^2\right] < +\infty$ and:

\begin{equation}
 \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow s} \mathbb{E}\left[\left(Z(x) - Z(s)\right)^2\right] = 0
\end{equation}

Question 1): Are these two conditions necessary and sufficient or are other conditions required for mean square continuity of $Z(x)$?

Question 2): Does the differentiability of realisation $z(x)$, also known as a sample path, of $Z(x)$ imply the existence of a derivative process $\dot{Z}(x)$ with finite variance?

Question 3): Is saying that $Z(x)$ is differentiable nowhere equivalent to saying that its derivative process $\dot{Z}(x)$ has infinite variance? For instance the Wiener process is [mean-square continuous](http://ece-research.unm.edu/bsanthan/ece541/mscon.pdf) yet [nowhere differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Qualitative_properties) and is often used to [represent the integral of white noise which has infinite variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process).

Question 4) Is it correct to say that mean-square differentiability of $Z(x)$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition for the differentiability of any realisation $z(x)$? But rather that if a process is both mean-square differentiable and [separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258671/mean-square-differentiability) then its samples paths are differentiable.